# Adding a LowPassFilter to PWMOscillator in AudioKit v5

Tags: audiokit

I am playing around with AKv5, and I am trying to add a LowPassFilter after an PWMOscillator, using the PWMOscillator recipe in the cookbook as a base.

[PWMOscillator] -> [LowPassFilter] -> Out

It seems like it should be pretty straight forward, and I have added the code below to the basic PWMOscillator Cookbook recipe.  But the LowPassFilters doesn't seem to have any effect, like it is being bypassed.

I have compared this with the LowPassFilter Recipe in the cookbook, and there does not seem to be anything I am missing compared to that example.

So I am hoping people have and idea why I cannot hear the LowPassFilter do anything?

Am I missing something super obvious?

Thanks in Advance.

```
struct PWMOscillatorData {
    var isPlaying: Bool = false
    /// Pulse Width ranges from 0.001 to .5 (Default: .5)
    var pulseWidth: AUValue = 0.5
    /// Frequency (Hz) ranges from 10 to 22050 (Default: 6900)
    var frequency: AUValue = 440
    /// Amplitude ranges from 0 to 1
    var amplitude: AUValue = 0.1
    /// Ramp Duration ranges from 0 to ? Seconds
    var rampDuration: AUValue = 1
    /// Cutoff Frequency (Hz) ranges from 10 to 22050 (Default: 6900)
    var cutoff: AUValue = 20
    /// Resonance (dB) ranges from -20 to 40 (Default: 0)
    var resonance: AUValue = 0
}

class PWMOscillatorConductor: ObservableObject, KeyboardDelegate {
...
    let engine = AudioEngine()

    var osc: PWMOscillator
    var lpFilter: LowPassFilter
...
    @Published var data = PWMOscillatorData() {
        didSet {
            if data.isPlaying {
                osc.start()
                osc.$pulseWidth.ramp(to: data.pulseWidth, duration: data.rampDuration)
                osc.$frequency.ramp(to: data.frequency, duration: data.rampDuration)
                osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: data.amplitude, duration: 0.01)
            } else {
                osc.amplitude = 0.0
            }
            lpFilter.$cutoffFrequency.ramp(to: data.cutoff, duration: 0.01)
            lpFilter.$resonance.ramp(to: data.resonance, duration: 0.01)
        }
    }
...
    init() {
        osc = PWMOscillator()
        lpFilter = LowPassFilter(osc)
        engine.output = lpFilter
    }
...
    ParameterSlider(text: "Cutoff",
                    parameter: self.$pwmConductor.data.cutoff,
                    range: 10...11500).padding(5)
    ParameterSlider(text: "Resonance",
                    parameter: self.$pwmConductor.data.resonance,
                    range: -20...40 ).padding(5)
```

Test

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the LowPassFilter wasn't too happy with the Binded Variables.

I had to change the var = data as such.

```
@Published var data = PWMOscillatorData() {
    didSet {
        if data.isPlaying {
            osc.start()
            osc.$pulseWidth.ramp(to: data.pulseWidth, duration: data.rampDuration)
            osc.$frequency.ramp(to: data.frequency, duration: data.rampDuration)
            osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: data.amplitude, duration: 0.01)
        } else {
            osc.amplitude = 0.0
        }
        lpFilter.cutoffFrequency = data.cutoff
        lpFilter.resonance = data.resonance
    }
}
```